# Detect one out of five distinct voltage levels

Tags: arduino, ac, voltage-measurement

I got a fan on my roof which is powered via a five step manual transformer to control the speed. The transformer outputs a voltage of either 0, 90, 110, 135, 165 or 230V AC. I would like to use an Arduino to detect which level is currently selected. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? Preferably using some non-intrusive method if possible (measure electric field somehow?).

Comment: Sounds like XY-problem to me... Why not monitor the control signal instead?

Comment: Why not a tachometer? Very non-intrusive.

Comment: Hall effect sensor

Comment: Webcam- plus you can get images of whoever is switching it.

Comment: use a running average of the positive readings from a mic or hall-effect sensor. 16 samples a few ms apart should cover you. an inline bulb and CDS could work too.

Comment: Tachometer/CDS is both great alternatives, but I wasn't clear enough that I do not have any easy access to the fan. The control unit is placed indoors, and that is were I need to do my measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the means to draw a circuit at the moment, so here's a list of bits...

1. smallest 6V transformer that you can get
2. smallest bridge rectifier
3. smoothing capacitor, say 200uF
4. potential divider using a 1K trimmer to output 4.5V when the input is 230VAC
5. series of if - then tests to measure the output of this circuit connected to an analogue input
6. Arduino output to taste

You might want to include a low pass RC or LC filter after the smoothing capacitor (item 3) to get a faster response. This is a direct connection and you wanted indirect, but it's a lot simpler and more reliable than some magnetic coupled device. That might require amplification and further processing. Plus the transformer provides safety isolation.

This circuit effectively converts the AC input voltage to a 0 - 4.5VDC signal for direct input to the Arduino's ADC pin. So you'll get a reading of 0 to 922 units which you can then bracket in software. Remember that just before the trimmer, you'll get root(2) times the transformer output voltage. I'd leave a little headroom and not try to read ADC input right up to 1023 units. That allows for useful feedback if the voltage overshoots a little, rather than maxing out at 1023.

Comment: Can anybody weigh in? Would a transformer's output scale linearly with inputs well below it's nominal operating voltage?

Comment: Ok, sounds easy enough. And with a 6V transformer, you mean something like a 1:40 transformer with 500VAC isolation, right? Or since I will be using a 3.3V Arduino Pro Mini, a 1:70 would be best? (giving me a DC signal between 0 and 3.28V)

Comment: @user2910016 remember that you'll get root(2) times the transformer output voltage. I'd leave a little headroom and not try to read ADC input right up to 1023 units. I've not seem commercial transformers categorized by turns ratios. Just get a small one.

Comment: You can draw schematics on the website. There's a plug-in top left of the texty typey box.